# Administering SharePoint with PowerShell

Tags: administration, powershell, stsadm

I have a limited knowledge on Powershell, but from what I've seen, it can be very useful in admin/dev tasks.

What would I have to develop to get a nice toolset for WSS/Stsadm administration?

Is there something already done to help out in these tasks?

What about 2010? Will they deliver something OOTB for admin with PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get started with SharePoint and PowerShell here is a great resource by Nicklas Goude: [MOSS 2007 Script Collection](http://www.powershell.nu/2009/09/08/moss-2007-script-collection/).

And about PowerShell in SharePoint 2010; the publically released preview of the SDK and Ribbon documentation contained a set of references to PowerShell cmdlets. That's all I can say now, but just wait a few more days and we'll all see what MS have done...

/WW

Answer (score 1):

For huge and definitive source of awesome powershell cmdlets and extensions I strongly recommend Gary Lapointe's http://stsadm.blogspot.com/

You'll find links to the list of the commands and his download page link on the right hand side.

Sorry I can't discuss SharePoint 2010 yet due to the NDA that is still in place, but expect to be really impressed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this blog](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/zach/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can someone please list a few examples of when you would be better off writing a PowerShell script than writing a Console Application?

Comment: I am convinced that PowerShell is going to be BIG for SharePoint 2010, looking at the investment Microsoft has put into providing hundreds of powerful Cmdlets.

Comment: You should ask this as a new question, would be interested to know!